# How can I make pokestops and gyms around me?

Tags: pokemon-go

How can I make pokestops and gyms around me? This game isn't just for adults it's also for kids not all mothers let their kids go where they want. There is a pokestop pretty close to me but I can't walk all the way over there crazy things happen and the gyms are even further the only time I get around them is when we are driving but of course when your driving it's only for a few seconds I can't have my mom park in the middle of the street to be in a gym or for a pokestop... How can I add them around me?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply add Pokestops, but you may request them here:
https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

If Niantic (the company who made the game) approves of the location, the Pokestop will be added.